# NSUserDefault is clearing once the application kills

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

For Saving the data

```
NSString *balSnapTokenFromResponce;
    balSnapTokenFromResponce = @"456294797493749873";

NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:balSnapTokenFromResponce forKey:@"Token"];
    [defaults synchronize];
```

For Retreiving the Data

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"Token"]
```

Comment: What is `[[NSString alloc]init]` for?

Comment: Weird...I just tested this code and it works for me. (The extra `[[NSString alloc]init]` is unnecessary though...the `@` in front of the string handles the alloc for you). The only thing I can thing of is that you're setting the default in a location that the code is never called.

Comment: at the time of application entered background state and after killing the app the value is cleared.

Comment: @Balu, are you sure that the value is being saved? Have you tried putting an `NSLog` there to see if the code is actually being called?

Comment: @LeejaySchmidt code is never called means plz can u explain

Comment: @WMios ya up to killing the application it working fine after killing or background it is clearing

Comment: @Balu, have you actually confirmed that this code is getting called?

Comment: @Balu as in the method that contains the first part of your code (where you `synchronize` your `defaults`) may not be executing before you kill the app. As @WMios has been saying, you should probably `NSLog` to see if the code is, in fact, being executed before the app is being killed.

Comment: @LeejaySchmidt  i'm synchronize mu defaults at the time of saving a value

Answer (score 2):

This, as shown, makes no sense:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"Token"]
```

You must do something with the return value:

```
NSString *balSnapTokenFromResponce = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"Token"];
```

Perhaps you are, but that's not clear from your question. Because otherwise the code you've posted should work, assuming it's getting called.